# Determine whether the set of vectors in P2 is linearly dependent or linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

I am getting conflicting answers to what the book has, am I setting this up correctly? I did row reduced echelon form in the calculator, I am unsure what to do from here or if I am doing it properly

Answer (score 1):

$3(2-x)-(6-7x+x^{2})-(4x-x^{2})=0$, so the polynomials are linearly dependent.

Comment: can you show how you got that?

Comment: Just by inspection!

Comment: can you show the step by step work?

Comment: You can first take a linear combination of the second and third so that the $x^{2}$ term gets cancelled and then  see if what you get is a multiple of the first polynomial. [n this case just adding the second and the third removes the second degree term and you will be left with $3$ times the first polynomial.

Comment: @isuckatprogramming Alternatively, you can first take a linear combination of the first and second polynomials so that the constant term is cancelled, and see that what you get is a multiple of the third. There are many ways to go here. I don't suggest starting with the first-degree term, though.

Comment: If somebody can show the work on how to go about this I will check it, final exam tomorrow and I must know an approach, it has been so long since ive done these I am reviewing